# pysparkling H2OConf interfering with my application log

Tags: python, logging, pyspark, h2o, sparkling-water

Here is my code:

```
from pysparkling import H2OConf #commenting this line makes it work
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='my_log.log',level=logging.INFO)
logging.info('test')
```

I cannot get the log file to get created, unless I comment the first line of the code. If I do that, then everything works as normal. I'm assuming it's an import inside `H2OConf` that messes up the handlers. Anybody experience anything similar?

I run the script with

`spark-submit --master yarn script.py`

Thanks